# How to exactly diagonalize a system with $Z_2\times Z_2$ symmetry?

Tags: computational-physics, topology, many-body, topological-phase, anderson-localization

I am studying the localization protected SPT phase, and try to compute the level spacing ratio of Hamiltonian,

$$H=\sum_kJ_kZ_{k-1}X_kZ_{k+1}+\sum_kh_kX_{k}X_{k+1}.$$

We can check that this Hamiltonian has a $Z_2\times Z_2$ symmetry and is in a deep topological phase when $J_k\gg h_k$. Although we can check that this system can be many-body localized if the randomness of $J_k$ is large (ref: Localization and topology protected quantum coherence at the edge of hot matter), and can be detected by the level spacing ratio (localized $\sim0.38$ and ergodic $\sim 0.52$).

I try to directly diagonalize this Hamiltonian, while find the level spacing ratio is near 0.38 even with small randomness. This is due to the $Z_2\times Z_2$ symmetry. My question is that, how can I resolve the $Z_2\times Z_2$ symmetry in the Hamiltonian and focus only on one of the symmetry sectors?

I know I should fix the basis in one symmetry sector firstly, but I have no idea how to do this since direct count the basis is too tedious.

Comment: When you build the Hilbert space for exact diagonalization, work in the eigenbasis of $X_k$ and only have basis states with definite values of $\prod_{k \text{ even}}X_k$ and $\prod_{k \text{ odd}}X_k$.

Comment: Many thanks, i understand this. I have another question. If I want to ED a Floquet quench system (let's say the original H in the main question and another H satisfies the Z2 x Z2 symmetry), I can get the block Floquet unitary in a special symmetry sector and get its logarithmic to compute the level spacing ratio. Is there another way to do this so that i can skip the logarithmic step, since its time expensive?